# How to remove texlive with Pacman

Tags: archlinux, pacman-package-manager

I installed texlive with Pacman in Archlinux. I want to remove all the installed packages now because I found them too big and a website called overleaf can meet most of my needs.

But there are too many packages contained in texlive, listed as below.

```
texinfo  texlive-formatsextra  texlive-latexextra  texlive-publishers
texlive-bibtexextra  texlive-games  texlive-music  texlive-science     
texlive-bin  texlive-genericextra  texlive-pictures  
texlive-core  texlive-htmlxml  texlive-plainextra 
texlive-fontsextra  texlive-humanities  texlive-pstricks
```

I tried `sudo pacman -R texinfo`, and change different parameters like `-Rd`, `-Rsn`. They all failed on dependency checking.

I tried `sudo pacman -Rc texinfo` but it tells me the next 7 packages will be removed, even including gdb!!!

```
drkonqi-5.9.5.1-1  gdb-7.12.1-3  gdb-common-7.12.1-3  guile-2.2.1-1
guile2.0-2.0.14-1  make-4.2.1-2  texinfo-6.3-1
```

So how to remove the texlive family nicely?

Comment: I think I've solved this problem. I still used the command `sudo pacman -Rc` to remove certain package and all the packages depend on it. For the Texlive problem, `sudo pacman -Rc texlive-bin` or `sudo pacman -Rc texlive-core` can remove Texlive tool nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise to go with `pacman -Rs package`, from the `pacman -R --help` output:

```
-c, --cascade        remove packages and all packages that depend on them
-s, --recursive      remove unnecessary dependencies
```

the `-c` option might delete packages needed by other packages, the `-s` will only delete them if they are not depended on by other packages on the system.

Comment: I think you want only `s`, it already removes unnecessary dependencies. From the docs on `-c`:
"This operation is recursive and must be used with care, since it can remove         many potentially needed packages."

Answer (score 1):

to delete texlive with relate files:
`sudo pacman -Rcns texlive-bin`
more information in this page: https://linux-packages.com/manjaro-linux/package/texlive-bin